# How would you design a mac address table (essentially a fast look up table)?

Tags: data-structures, software-design

This is a programming question related to computer networking. Essentially every router/switch has a mac address table which it looks up to get the interface port on which it has to forward packets on. The table itself looks like this:

[image]

So basically given the two keys, vlan and the mac address, a lookup is done on the table and the value of the port (last column) is looked up. In practice, the table might have thousands of rows and the value needs to be returned as fast as possible. So my question is what is the best way to design this lookup table? I was asked this in the interview and I thought of using a hash table, with the combination of vlan and mac address as the key. But it was not convincing. Please suggest a good design for this.

Answer (score 1):

For a software only solution I would go for a hash table too. But switches are a specialized hardware and they are manufactured in big quantities. So it is reasonable to develop a specialized memory hardware for them. The next thing is that you need a similar hardware for a CPU cache because when you need to fetch something from RAM you first need to find out if the cache line is loaded in-to a cache.

With that knowledge you can proceed to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Associativity) or to [this article](https://www.cs.umd.edu/class/sum2003/cmsc311/Notes/Memory/fully.html).

Update: beside searching MAC addresses you have to remove old entries to prevent your table from becoming too big. May be you have not described how to do that and something like LRU cache was expected from you. LRU can be implemented over hash table, just add extra linked list for remove queue. Or instead of LRU you can make a hash table with tricky conflict solving strategy: have a fixed number of buckets and limit bucket size too. If bucket is full, drop something from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a hashtable ( `map< class_representing_entry, int >` in C++ or `HashMap< Class_representating_entry, Integer > in java`).

A key part here is to have a proper hash function, e.g. you can use the combination of vlan and mac address, to effectively make a lookup in `O(1)`

Alternatively, I think a trie data-structure would help reduce memory footprint, if the number of entries is really huge.

Comment: Your solution will consume RAM without limit and will lead to a crash when it no more RAM will be available. And user2311285 has stated that hastable alone "was not convincing".

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth noting that an array/list with brute force might be surprisingly fast - 'thousands of items' is not many at all.

In a similar theme, a sorted array/list also works, allowing binary searches.

Remember, *all* data structures are O(1) if n has a limit.

Comment: Yes, but the table itself is dynamic. It keeps changing i.e, entries are subject to be removed/modified any time. So to keep it sorted all the time itself would be a challenge, I think.

Comment: @user2311285 that's entirely possible, the question is does it matter.  A switch/router only needs to worry about a few MAC addresses, and they should be added and removed fairly infrequently.  Keeping such a small list sorted is trivial, even for a tiny processor.  For my LAN, I guesstimate about 10 devices, with that number or less of additions and removals each day.  Lookups occur on the order of millions to tens of millions of times a day.

Comment: Not a few MAC addresses. You do not have many devices, but installations with thousand devices are possible. And a good switch can handle tenth simultaneous gigabit (or 10G) connections. So it can be millions or tenth of millions of lookups per second. Iteration over a whole table for every packet will take much too much time. .

Comment: @AlexeyGuseynov 1) Different market segments will make different tradeoffs. 2) Do not confuse a network with thousands of devices with an individual switch. 3) Until you've sat down and actually benchmarked the comparisons, any performance comments are purely speculative.

Comment: 1) Yes. And low end is not interesting because there is no performance problem. 2) Switches do serve entire network. You can stack them up to 5 levels and they do routing for the whole net. 3) As I've stated in my answer, this is a classical problem, so all needed benchmarks have been done and tested by many engineers. Caching algorithms are part of high school programs.

Comment: 1) Needs Reference.  2)  Possibly.  Needs Reference.  3)  Needs reference.    I think we're getting into an unproductive discussion.  For the purposes of an interview brute force should be considered, as well as hashing and LRU caches - and the relative merits of all should be discussed.